# How to display a "go down" hint arrow in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a *listview* with multiple rows whose length could exceed the size of the screen of the smartphone. I want to be sure **the user knows he has to keep scrolling down to see all the entries of the list**.

So the first thing that came to my mind was to display a **fuzzy and glowing arrow on the bottom of the screen** (or just to make the bottom part of the *listview* glow) until the user starts scrolling down. How to display the arrow and set up its behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could display an `ImageView` fixed on the bottom of your view. You can set it a fuzzy drawable if you want.

Add this to your layout.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_arrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

And then in your code, you check when the list is scrolled if the last item has been drawn.

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if(totalItemCount != listView.getLastVisiblePosition() + 1){
             imageView.setVisible(View.GONE);
        }else{
             imageView.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't need a button to scroll down! (The user will scroll just as automatically implemented by the listview.) I just want a  "hint" to be displayed *over* the listview to make sure the user receives the message "Hey man, the list is not over yet!"

Comment: Okay then you'll have to check if the last item has been drawn. Will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Also to decide whether to show your button or not you can set a scroll listener on the listview and then call **list.canScrollVertically(-1)**. If the returned value is true than you can show your button. If it is false it means that user can see all of the content without scrolling and you don't need to show your button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            int position = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    imageViewDownArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    imageViewDownArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        }
    });
```

Comment: keep in mind OP is not using a recyclerView, he should but he is using listView